# Sobre comando de teclas (lua script)

Tags: string, lua, teclado, script, jogos

Tem alguma forma de eu colocar algo no lua script, para que, se eu pressionar uma tecla, ele responda com algum comando? Se sim, como?

Comment: Em qual contexto? Certamente tem mas cada lugar que o *script* for usado pode ser uma forma diferente.

Comment: Tipo o que o LÖVE faz? Dê mais detalhes do seu problema.

Comment: Eu queria fazer um script para garry's mod 13, então, eu gostaria com que ele respondesse com uma tecla, tal como: if crtl say hello

Comment: Tem que ver a API deste jogo, é ela que poderá invocar o *script* Lua. Não sei nem se o problema é sobre Lua. Como não conheço a API não tenho como ajudar.

Comment: Pra clarificar um pouco o que os outros já falaram: Lua é uma linguagem de programação projetada para ser embutida em projetos maiores. O que normalmente ocorre é que um jogo como o Gary's mod vai implementar um monte de funções básicas em C e disponibilizar essas funções para você usar de dentro do Lua (porque programar em Lua é bem mais fácil prum modder do que C). A biblioteca padrão de Lua é super super enxuta então qualquer coisa não trivial que você quiser vai ter que ser via uma dessas funções que o Gary's mod adicionou ao ambiente Lua.

Answer (score 1):

Na plataforma para criação de jogos chamado `Love 2d` é possível fazer isso.

Exemplo:

```
function love.keypressed(key)
    print(string.format("você apertou a letra '%s'", key)
end
```

Referência: https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keypressed